# Typescript gives ridiculous wrong year in new Date() function

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I am really pulling my hair now and going crazy:

```
  const {year, month} = req.headers;
  const date_range_from = new Date(year, month, 1);  
  const date_range_to = new Date(year, month + 1, 1); // wrong year; why?   
  
  console.log("year, month: ", year, month)
  console.log("date_range_from, date_range_to: ", date_range_from, date_range_to)
```

The console log gives:

```
year, month:  2021 6
date_range_from, date_range_to:  2021-06-30T15:00:00.000Z 2026-01-31T15:00:00.000Z
```

WHY 2026 ????
What is going on???

Comment: Your `month` value is probably a string, so `month + 1` evaluates to `61`, not `7`. Change it to `+month + 1` to verify.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a [mre] of this in an IDE; I'm surprised TypeScript isn't [warning you](https://tsplay.dev/w6Bjvw) that you are trying to call `new Date()` with strings instead of numbers.

Comment: @Pointy Instead of +month, use parseInt(month) - the latter is more readable and the parseInt is harder to miss.

Comment: @MontanaBurr but `parseInt()` has serious problems; `Number(month)` would be much better. However, `+month` is completely idiomatic in JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy Be that as it may, if you use +month, it's easy for a developer reading your code to miss the plus sign at the beginning. The "Number()" function call is a little harder to miss.

Comment: @MontanaBurr that's a fair point, but I don't hire developers like that :)

Comment: @jcalz—the OP code doesn't appear to be Typescript, anyway values passed to the Date constructor can be numbers or strings. I'll guess that since *month* is a string that it's calendar month, so should be `new Date(year, month - 1)` anyway. :-)

Comment: @RobG It's hard to tell since TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript.  (e.g., [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w2KLYN) is valid TypeScript and valid JavaScript).  The OP certainly seems to *think* TypeScript is involved (and actively providing incorrect years worthy of ridicule).  You may be right that no TypeScript compilers were harmed in the production of this code, but I guess I'll wait to see if Kid_Learning_C ever returns with an update here.